# WRONG ''send to/receiving'' address always displayed on trezor??

Tags: wallet, receiving, sendtoaddress

when using myetherwallet the wrong and completely unknown receiving address is always displayed on the trezor screen when im asked to confirm the addresses match, BUT, i sent a very tiny amount and it arrived safely and quickly to the correct address, do i need to send the unit back for a replacement?